# How to wait until Current Location dialog is answered to run a method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location, core-bluetooth

What is the best practice for pushing a view controller based on the feedback from the requesting Current Location iOS-based dialog (shown in the image below)?

I am trying to determine after the selections is made to either success -> send the user onward in the flow OR fail -> show a screen that requires they allow current location.

I've gotten as far as calling this method from a method where a button-press allocates CLLocationManager:

```
- (void) confirmInfo {


    BOOL locationAllowed = [CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled];

    if (locationAllowed==NO) {
        // Show the how-to viewcontroller
    } else {
        // Go to the next step onboarding
    }

}
```

But I do not know how to wait until the input comes back from the dialog to choose which VC to show the user.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have Delegate method user will allow or even if user dont allow.. and from that response you can continue you push pop.

Else even is you can try block based structure to maintain your flow. 
following link may help you.. 
https://github.com/intuit/LocationManager
or 
https://github.com/FuerteInternational/FTLocationManager

```
INTULocationManager *locMgr = [INTULocationManager sharedInstance];
[locMgr requestLocationWithDesiredAccuracy:INTULocationAccuracyCity
                                   timeout:10.0
                      delayUntilAuthorized:YES  // This parameter is optional, defaults to NO if omitted
                                     block:^(CLLocation *currentLocation, INTULocationAccuracy achievedAccuracy, INTULocationStatus status) {
                                         if (status == INTULocationStatusSuccess) {
                                             // Request succeeded, meaning achievedAccuracy is at least the requested accuracy, and
                                             // currentLocation contains the device's current location.
                                         }
                                         else if (status == INTULocationStatusTimedOut) {
                                             // Wasn't able to locate the user with the requested accuracy within the timeout interval.
                                             // However, currentLocation contains the best location available (if any) as of right now,
                                             // and achievedAccuracy has info on the accuracy/recency of the location in currentLocation.
                                         }
                                         else {
                                             // An error occurred, more info is available by looking at the specific status returned.
                                         }
                                     }];
```

Answer (score 0):

First, create a `CLLocationManager`, then set your controller to its delegate, finally call `[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocations];` to display the dialog.

Then use the `CLLocationManagerDelegate` methods to determine what the user chose:

On success,

`– locationManager:didUpdateLocations:`

gets called. Otherwise

`– locationManager:didFailWithError:`